# Not able to connect Eclipse with SQL Server

Tags: java, sql, eclipse

I am working on a java project with which I need to connect with database.
I am using Eclipse and SSMS (because I found it easy to use and manage). I know how to connect eclipse with SSMS. Issue is I don't know the password and username of my sql server. I installed SQL server and SSMS. No where I was asked to set username and password. I open my SSMS like this.

[image: Opening of SSMS]

Now I don't know about any password and username and I am so confused that what to put in the user name and password field below.

[image: Eclipse]

Comment: For starters, SQL Server isn’t the same as MySQL you’re using in your connection. You’ll need to tell it to connect to the correct server type. Also you’re not connecting Eclipse to anything, it’s just an IDE you use to develop and it’s your application that’s connecting.

Comment: Read "[Connecting with Integrated Authentication On Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017)"

Comment: Connection string is using mysql driver and you must be using windows authentication for connecting. If you want yourself to save from pain create a new user with desired permissions using SSMS and use that in your connection string

Answer (score 1):

These are basic and common newbie developer problems. Here is what I recommend after dealing with tons of SQL server problems while I was in college.

1. OPEN your CMD and type in sqllocaldb i and check what servers are available in your computer, try connecting to any of those that are shown
2. Check your SQL Server Configuration Manager(is it working)
3. Did you initialize your SQL SERVER service? type services.msc and check if it available.
4. If not one of this works, try reinstalling and READ the requirements maybe your SQL installer did not include SQL service configuration, you might need to download full SQL that includes service configurations